# What does the asterisk in the netstat output mean?

Tags: networking

```
# netstat -at
Active Internet connections (servers and established)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State
tcp        0      0 localhost:30037         *:*                     LISTEN
tcp        0      0 localhost:ipp           *:*                     LISTEN
tcp        0      0 *:smtp                  *:*                     LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 localhost:ipp           [::]:*                  LISTEN
```

What does the asterisk `*` in `*:smtp` mean ?

Why is there no IP address shown?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a wildcard meaning "any".

For example, in the third line:

```
tcp        0      0 *:smtp                  *:*                     LISTEN
```

The first *, in `*:smtp`, means the process is listening on all of the IP addresses the machine has.  The second *, in `*:*`, means connections can come from any IP address.  The third *, in `*:*`, means the connection can originate from any port on the remote machine.

Comment: Thank you, that helped. Is it right to say, the first * means 'listen on all network interfaces the system has' ?

Comment: Yes, in the "Local Address" column.  (It has different meaning in the "Foreign Address" column)

Comment: Does this mean that it listens on both IPv4 and IPv6?

Comment: ipp does, its listed twice, once with tcp and also with tcp6